# How to change the focus of text input when using custom text input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, textinput

1.Here is my custom text input custom component i define props ref which i want to use in
parent component

```
export const InputField = ({
placeholder,
onChangeText,
placeholderTextColor,
showSecureIcon,
isSecure,
onPressIcon,
keyboardType,
returnKeyType,
maxLength,
secureIconColor,
handleUseCallBack,
ref,
value
 }) => {


return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <TextInput
            style={styles.input}
            placeholder={placeholder}
            onChangeText={onChangeText}
            placeholderTextColor={placeholderTextColor}
            autoCapitalize="none"
            secureTextEntry={isSecure}
            keyboardType={keyboardType}
            returnKeyType={returnKeyType}
            maxLength={maxLength}
            value={value}
            ref={ref}
        />
        <View style={styles.iconContainer}>
            {showSecureIcon ?
                <TouchableOpacity
                    onPress={onPressIcon}
                >
                    <Ionicons
                        name={isSecure ? "eye-off-sharp" : "eye-sharp"}
                        color={secureIconColor}
                        size={constants.vw(25)}
                    />
                </TouchableOpacity>

                :
                null
            }
        </View>
    </View>
)
}
```

2-Now the part where i want to change my ref
in this field i create the text inputs field of password and confirm where i want to change
my focus

```
   const passwordRef = useRef(null);
   const confirmPasswordRef = 
   useRef(null);
   
   const onSubmitEditing=()=>{
   confirmPasswordRef.current.focus();
    }

                 <View style={{ marginTop: constants.vh(66) }}>
                <Components.InputField
                    placeholder={constants.ConstStrings.setANewPassword}
                    ref={passwordRef}
                    onSubmitEditing={()=>onSubmitEditing()}
                    onChangeText={(text) => setState({
                        ...state,
                        password: text
                    })}
                />
            </View>
            <View style={{ marginTop: constants.vh(20) }}>
                <Components.InputField
                    ref={confirmPasswordRef}
                    placeholder={constants.ConstStrings.confirmPassword}
                    onChangeText={(text) => setState({
                        ...state,
                        confirm_password: text
                    })}
                />
            </View>
```

This part is the end part qwertyuiopsdf;';dsyuiopoiuteweryuiopuytreep[gfjklvcvbnm,mvcxzxcewqwe[poiuyd

Comment: What is the problem with this code?

Comment: Reference not change when i submit the text input

Comment: Can you either accept or decline the answer, please? If you mark it as correct, then the people looking at your question will know that it's correct, and if it's not, we can look at it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you've created a custom input component, but haven't given to it the instructions on how to handle different methods.

So, in your case, the generic `Input` component knows what method is `focus`, but your custom one doesn't.

What you should do:

1. Make your input component a `forwardRef` one so that you can pass a `ref` to it and then be able to do actions on it.
2. Use `useImperativeHandle` so that you can call internal methods of your ref.
3. Create a `focus` fn which in your custom input will basically call the `focus` method of your ref.

You cannot pass the ref in props as you are doing, that just doesn't work in React.

I suppose all of your components are functional, in that case:

```
export const InputField = React.forwardRef({
placeholder,
...
}, ref) => { // pass a ref to here, this way you will let React know to associate the ref from external component to an internal ref

const textInput = useRef(null); // Create a ref to pass to your input

useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({ // To be able to call `focus` from outside using ref
  focus,
});

const focus = textInput.current.focus();

return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <TextInput
            ref={textInput}
            style={styles.input}
            ...
        />
        ...
    </View>
)
}
```

And then in your component you just have to pass a fresh `ref` created by `useRef` and then you'll be able to call `focus` on in.

Tell me whether that solves it for you!